# Nginx proxy_read_timeout for large number of requests

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Based on what an individual shall specify an amount of :

```
proxy_read_timeout
proxy_connect_timeout
proxy_send_timeout
```

My team specified it with 150, and I want to make sure that their choice is accurate.

Is there any formula one could use to calculate ?

Answer (score 1):

proxy_read_timeout is set to 60 seconds. You should adjust this value based on your requirements. For a large number of requests, you might need a longer timeout.

proxy_read_timeout = (Average Response Time * Maximum Simultaneous Requests) + Desired Request Handling Time

1. Average Response Time is 0.5 seconds.
2. Maximum Simultaneous Requests is 100.
3. Desired Request Handling Time is 5 seconds

proxy_read_timeout = (0.5 seconds * 100) + 5 seconds = 50 seconds + 5 seconds = 55 seconds

---

1. proxy_connect_timeout = Average Network Latency + Backend Server Load Time + Desired Maximum Connection Establishment Time
2. proxy_send_timeout = Time to Transmit Request Data + Backend Server Readiness + Desired Maximum Request Transmission Time generally people have value 60s for all .

but you can optimize by regularly monitoring

Comment: Thank you for your time, may I know the formulas for the rest?
1. proxy_connect_timeout
2. proxy_send_timeout

If you could provide me the reference to deep dive more